# d3js how to select the element i'm currently working on

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3.js to draw a scatterplot. I want to add some text with multiple lines to it. How do i select the element, i'm currently working on?

```
var text= this.topBarElements.selectAll("#text").data(this.projectMap.text);
      text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "text")
        .attr("x", (d:rest.resource) => {
          return (this.xScale(d.date));
        })
        .attr("y", 40)
        .append("tspan")
        .text((d:rest.resource) => {
         var texts = ((d3.selectAll(text)[0]));
            if (d.title.length > 7) {
              console.log(d3.selectAll(this.topBarElements.text));

              texts.append("tspan").text(d.title.substring(0, 5)).attr("x", this.xScale(d.date)).attr("y", 34);
              texts.append("tspan").text(d.title.substring(5)).attr("x", this.xScale(d.date)).attr("y", 46);
              return "";
            }
          return d.title;  
        )
    }
```

Basically, i add data to it, and if the title is too long i add two tspan elements with half the title in it. This works, but since i have selected all 7 of my text elements, it does this 7 times.

I tried using this, but that just parses the whole svg element i'm drawing on.

Comment: Pls add a fiddle for better understading

Comment: What do you mean by the 'element you r currently working on'? Are you selecting the element manually?

Comment: Use `d3.select("text.<classname>")`, and apply a class to the text that you want to work on when you first add it to the plot. Or, if you have text bound to data then you should be able to select it using the data based on mouseover events or the like.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after is:

```
d3.select(this);
```

Normally when you've got an event, or a function that is operating on an item, `this` will be the HTML element that you're operating on. Doing `d3.select(this)` will then convert that to a D3 selection. So if you want to enumerate your `texts` for example you could use:

d3.selectAll("text")
  .each(function(d) { 
     d3.select(this); // This is a text item
  });